# How two check results of execution of two separate functions?

Tags: javascript

I'm checking data in two separate modules for two separate purposes.
As for example:

```
//first Module
var moduleOne = (function(){
    function typeCheck(data) {
        if(typeof data == "string") {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return {
        typeCheck: typeCheck
    }
}());
```

And my second module is:

```
//second Module
var moduleTwo = (function(){
    function lengthCheck(data) {
        if(data.length > 4){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    return {
        lengthCheck: lengthCheck
    }
}());
```

When the both two modules result in `false` I want to alert that data is wrong.

```
//let str variable be an example to run those functions
var str = "string-data"
moduleOne.typeCheck(str);
moduleTwo.lengthCheck(str);
```

But in case if the data is `false` only in one case then everything else works as it is.

Comment: `if (!first() && !second())`...!?

Comment: no both two modules are in different files and their execution is in another file

Comment: But you *are* calling both functions from within the same context, no?! As shown in your example...!?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the project structure - but I think this should work:

```
    if(!moduleOne.typeCheck(str) && !moduleTwo.lengthCheck(str)){
        alert('Data is wrong!');
    }
```